# Online tool for calculating trading profits on multiple cypro currency pairs

Tags: tools

I'm looking for a tool (preferably online) which would help me follow profits earned on muti crypto currency pairs.

Take a look at the example below

1. buy x_1 btc for y_1 usd
2. buy x_2 eth for y_2 btc
3. buy x_3 zec for y_3 btc
4. sell x_4 eth for y_4 btc

Kraken only shows the current total value of all crypto and how much of each crypto I own. It's kind of hard to keep track which pairs are profiting and by how much.

I'd like to

1. Be able to enter every transaction I make
2. See the list of all pairs with profits on a pair
3. See the list of currencies with profits on usd